# lsmod command not working in windows subsystem for linux

Tags: lubuntu, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed windows subsystem for linux with ubunut version 20.04 in windows 10 from microsoft store .I tried to install netextender software in that subsystem through terminal.But I get below error message in that.

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1668 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
```

I checked with ubuntu os laptop by entering command `lsmod` but that gives list of modules,but that not available in windows subsystem for linux.When i search regarding this issue,it shows some kernel issue in windows like that.But i cant understand and why this not working.Can anyone help for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

##### Short Answer

You are likely running WSL1.  `lsmod` requires WSL2.

##### Explanation

Start with `wsl -l -v` (from PowerShell or CMD) to confirm your WSL version.  You'll probably see something like:

```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         1
```

One of the primary differences between WSL1 and WSL2:

- WSL1 is a "translation layer" that attempts to convert Linux syscalls to the Windows kernel's API.
- WSL2 is a "virtualized" environment that runs under a real Linux kernel.

So, for example, when the `ls` command gets a list of files:

- Under WSL1, Windows provides that list of files using the Windows API to get the files in the WSL rootfs.
- Under WSL2, the Linux kernel is using the ext4 filesystem in a virtual disk to retrieve the list of files.  For files on Windows drives (e.g. `/mnc/c`), it uses the 9P network protocol to obtain the files.

It's really pretty amazing just how much WSL1 is able to do given this.  But there *are* limitations.  `lsmod` is one of them.  While WSL1 does provide certain `/proc` mapping (such as processes), the concept of "kernel modules" doesn't make much sense to do with a Windows mapping.

It might be possible to list Windows drivers, but that wouldn't really provide any benefit.

##### Convert to WSL2

Assuming you already have WSL2 *enabled* on Windows, you can convert your Ubuntu instance to WSL2 using:

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
```

While this command is pretty safe, I would still recommend backing up your instance first with:

```
wsl --export Ubuntu backup.tar
```

As with the initial `wsl` command, this is a Windows command, so it will need to be run from PowerShell or CMD.

##### Installing/Enabling WSL2

If you do not have WSL2 enabled, you can do so by following Steps 2-5 of [this doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual).

Enabling WSL2 does *not* update already installed instances, so you will still need to do the conversion step (`wsl --set-version`) above.

##### Limitations

But note that the kernel provided with WSL already has all available modules compiled in, so the result of `lsmod` will just be an empty list.

You *can* compile your own kernel with loadable modules if you'd like.  Please see the [WSL Linux kernel Github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel) and the [WSL Doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#global-configuration-options-with-wslconfig) for how to load WSL with your custom kernel.

But hopefully that won't be required for Netextender.

Comment: when i run this command wsl -l -v,it shows - Command 'wsl' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install wsl.shoud i run this command and install wsl?

Comment: @user3157334 (Side note:  Good timing) Run the `wsl` command from PowerShell or CMD.  I'll edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: when run wsl in powershell,same above response comes.

Comment: @user3157334 Double-check that.  The error message *"Command xxx not found, but can be installed"* is a bash shell message.  I can't think of any way you would see that response in PowerShell.  If the command weren't found in PowerShell, you'd get, *"The term 'xxxxx' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, ..."*  You might have *entered* WSL from PowerShell with just a `wsl` command.  In that case, just type `exit` (or Ctrl+D) to exit WSL back to PowerShell.